# Open Source Shopping Cart Software

Tags: shopping-cart

I've come into a bit of an issue lately regarding shopping cart software, and I would like some recommendations.

I have been an OsCommerce developer for years now, and I'm finding a lot of my clients are wanting updated looking backends ... OSC is fantastic, but the fact that its not being updated anymore and that it's clunky and table-based is taking up quite a bit of my time.

I have built a few sites on Magento, and although it has quite a good backend, it is the slowest shopping cart I have ever come across in my time, that and the fact that modifying it takes years, has convinced me not to use that again.

So, I like any input as to what people are finding good in today's open source shopping cart software.

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/) is opensource & free.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [PrestaShop](http://www.prestashop.com/), it's also an opensource and free e-commerce solution. Can't really point advantages/disadvantages though, as I've got no basis for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Why not [osCmax](http://www.oscmax.com) since it's derived from osCommerce; what you're familiar with?

If not, then [Zen Cart](http://www.zen-cart.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually trying to [find a good shopping](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28139/which-ecommerce-framework-is-fast-and-easy-to-customize) cart myself, although with limited success so far. I heard mixed opinions about OpenCart and PrestaShop, and I personally tried the first. I didn't like it much, as I found it very rough and poorly documented. I wanted to implement a plugin and all the information I could get was "copy from a similar one", which any good developer would recognize as the worst possible way of doing things (coding without understanding, also called "programming by coincidence"). Not to mention some CSRF vulnerabilities.

PrestaShop, based on what I read, has different issues, such as very strict templating rules, lack of features (most of which are supplied by expensive plugins) and some annoying incompatibilities. I haven't tried it yet, though.

I found two articles about the two carts, which highlight a not-so-brilliant experience with both:

- [Should We Use OpenCart?](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/05/should-we-use-opencart/)
- [Should We Use PrestaShop?](http://blog.ericlamb.net/2010/05/should-we-use-prestashop/)

They are from 2010, therefore things may have improved since the day they were written, but, from my experience with OC, they are still (and unfortunately) quite actual.